# Unusual way of finding probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question** : A box contain 4 defective and 6 good bulbs. Two bulbs are drawn at random without replacement. Find the probability that both bulbs are good.

**My way for Answer** : I have first found a sample space of the experimental outcomes i.e., to draw two balls at random and found 90(10x9) ways of doing this.

Of these elementary events(mutually exclusive and exhaustive events of sample space) favourable outcomes are 6x5(30)

Assuming all elementary events have equally likely probability the required probability is $\frac 13$

**Text book way** : Let A and B be the events of drawing a good bulb in 1st and 2nd draw respectively.
Here $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B/A)$ 
$= \frac 6{10}*\frac 59=\frac 13$

**My doubt** : By definition we define $P(B/A)=\frac {P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$
So we initially have to know the probability of intersection of A and B and the probability of B to find out the conditional probability of B/A.

But here they are doing it weird,**How come they know $P(B/A)$ without knowing $P(A\cap B)$**

I am following the axiomatic approach to probability.

Comment: I see the above weird thing in other problems too....

Comment: @G-man, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition

Comment: In axiomatic approach we define it that way as also indicated by Barry in the comment @G-man . What you are saying is to do it in classical approach which is pretty straight forward due to the change of sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be missing here is a clear (axiomatic) formulation of the notion that, when working with finite sets, "drawn at random" means that each item is assigned equal probability of being drawn, and then a theorem of some sort relating $P(B|A)$ to the notion of being "drawn at random" from a *subset* of the original finite set.  In this case, conditioning on the first bulb being good leaves you with a sample space consisting of $9$ possible results for the second draw, only $5$ of which are good.

Comment: Oh Yes, I made a real silly mistake.... most of the times the textbook followed classical approach and I was stressing axiomatic way in every problem, which would certainly mean you are right.....and he even gave the theorem you mentioned!!! Thankyou....